# PHP and select list

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this html code:

```
<select name='plan_id'>  
 <option value="1" >Basic</option>  
 <option value="2" selected="selected">Basic Gold</option>  
 <option value="3" >Silver</option>  
</select>
```

and php code:

```
$from = $_POST['plan_id'];  
var_dump($from);
```

and I got string `''` (length=0).

How do I fix it to get the selected value?

Comment: What? Why? I need only 1 argument..

Comment: I suspect your HTML is broken. Posting the whole form would allow us to confirm or refute that claim. But you can also check yourself, e.g. http://validator.w3.org.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in that piece of code. It might be you 1)Used method="get" instead of "post"; 2)Something else in the form is not right, maybe a submit button not submitting (should be input type="submit")

Comment: I don't do submit. I want to get the default value ('2'), before the submit

Comment: Yeah, I thnk you have answered your question now...:/  How can you get a value in php without submitting it? If you were using AJAX, you forgot to tell us a lot of things. Otherwise, you're just going against logic.

Comment: @Avigayil - PHP is a server side language. When the page reaches the browser, PHP has long finished running.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are same sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if( isset($_POST['plan_id']) ){
    var_dump($_POST['plan_id']);
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="plan_id">
        <option value="1" >Basic</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Basic Gold</option>
        <option value="3" >Silver</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```